# How can I set visibility of views based on value in viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm new to android development so this may be simple but I just cant see what is wrong.

I have a data class (which is actually a room entity if that matters) , for example :

```
@Entity(...)
data class MyDataClass (
   ...
   var dataType:Int=0,
   ...
)
```

In viewmodel I have

```
val data = MutableLiveData<MyDataClass>()
```

In the viewmodel init block this is initialised

In my activity layout xml I have various views to allow editing of the data class

There is a spinner in the layout which edits the dataType :

```
<Spinner
   ...
   android:selectedItemPosition="@={viewmodel.data.dataType}"
/>
```

So far it works.

I then have a view in the layout

```
<LinearLayout
   ...
   app:hideIfZero="@{viewmodel.data.dataType}"
/>
```

where the hideIfZero binding adapter is

```
@BindingAdapter("app:hideIfZero")
fun hideIfZero(view: View, number:Int) {
    view.visibility = if (number == 0) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
}
```

When I run the app, I can edit all of my fields including the dataType via the spinner. However when I change the spinner value the visibility of the LinearLayout is not changed.

What am I missing ?

Do I need to somehow tell the activity to refresh the complete layout. Any examples I've found seem to imply this should happen automatically.

Comment: You're binding to the `dataType` member, which is just an `Int`. From the databinding documentation: _"Any plain-old object can be used for data binding, but modifying the object doesn't automatically cause the UI to update"_.

Comment: Michael - so is there a way to mark (annotate) dataType so that modification does cause a UI update ?